# Isotope video gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I have created the Isotope gallery for my site which works fine and now i want to add one more functionality to the gallery that when the image is click so that div container expand to the specific width and height and video shall play in that div. Is there any default feature of isotope gallery which can handle this? any suggestions or ideas are most welcome

so far my code looks like this

```
<div id="naviso">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat1">cat1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat2">cat2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat3">cat3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat4">cat4</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="container" class="grid_12">
  <div id="box" class="cat1">
    <div class="box-img">
<a href="" rel="Shadowbox;height=540;width=960"><img src="/files/Image.png" alt="S"></a>
    </div>
  </div> 

<div id="box" class="cat1 cat2">
    <div class="box-img">
<a href="" rel="Shadowbox;height=540;width=960"><img src="/files/Image.png" alt="S"></a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $container = $('#container');
// initialize isotope
$container.isotope({
  // options...
});

// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('#naviso ul a').click(function(){
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: This should not be an isotope issue. I know that shadowbox supports videos. You define youtube link and on click overlay pops up and video plays.

Answer (score 0):

Isotope provides a lot of Demonstrations how such things are done. 
What you most likely want is a Resizable Object. 
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/relayout.html

As far as I remember (i did something like that), you destroy the current Object and Insert a new One. Then you let Isotope simply, rearrange the whole Isotope container. I did that, back then, with different States (div class or id) and just reacted with different Cases to that. Example: 
if (class == big) 
onclick (make small)
elseif (class == small)
onclick (make big)

I cant tell you the Details right now, but assuming you are able to work with jQuery, this is something you can easy manage to do. Simply look at the Demos and some of their Methods they provide with Isotope.